# Adding a Comment to a Node With SnakeYaml

Tags: java, comments, yaml, nodes, snakeyaml

As part of a large project I am working on, I am constructing a YAML file in memory, and then dumping it to a file, using SnakeYaml in this entire process. My YAML file is around 500 lines long and meant to be used by people who have no programming experience whatsoever, so comments on most nodes is a must. My past three hours have been spent staring at the [SnakeYaml Documentation](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation), as well as Googling a fair bit, but with no results. I can conclude one of three things:

1. I may have missed it completely.
2. Its not there (unlikely, if it *does* exists).
3. Its not possible.

I'm leaning towards the third, but before I write my own YAML dumper, I wished to ask the StackOverflow community whether this is possible? So, is it? Something among the lines of `yamlfile.setComment("a.random.node", "Its a random node!");` would be bliss, but it doesn't matter to me if it isn't anywhere close to as simple.

In the case that it is not, could someone give me some pointers as to what I should do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the comments are not part of the representation tree, they are ignored by SnakeYAML.
Since a YAML document is nothing but a text document, any Template processor can be used.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I ended up doing.

Comment: @Xyene Can you please tell me which template engine you used?

Comment: It appears SnakeYaml 2.0 has a `setProcessComments()` on both `LoaderOptions` and `DumperOptions`.  However, I cannot seem to get it to preserve comments associated with loaded data on dump.  The feature isn't well-documented.